# How can I set MySQL Workbench to automatically disconnect from server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to set Workbench to automatically disconnect from the server when idle?

The command line mysql client disconnects when idle and then reconnects when you run a query.
I'd like Workbench to disconnect automatically, too.

I cannot modify the server's timeout settings. But the command line client works as desired with the current server settings.

Answer (score 13):

See the MySQL Workbench preferences:

[image]

There's no automatic reconnection however. You can however use `menu -> Query -> Reconnecto to Server` for manual reconnection.