# MySQL Workbench: Reconnecting to database when "MySQL server has gone away"?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a lot of tabs and queries open in MySQL workbench. I left it open before I went to sleep, but this morning I am getting an error `MySQL server has gone away` when trying to run queries.

The database is up, and I am able to connect to it if I open a new connection on MySQL workbench, but the current connection is dead. How do I reconnect?

I don't want to open a new connection as I would have to copy my queries and tabs over.

Comment: It is annoying that they don't reconnect automatically, isn't it.

Comment: Yes haven't the makers of this or pgAdmin ever used SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Done it.

```
Query Menu -> Reconnect to Server
```

Comment: is there any automated setting that reconnects it every 60 seconds or so?

Comment: @aimiliano see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718417/how-can-i-set-mysql-workbench-to-automatically-disconnect-from-server

Comment: Thank you, I had this problem too and bothered me until I found your answer :)

Comment: Crazy that this isn't on the Server menu!

Comment: A "Reconnect to Server" shortcut key would be useful, even if the automated reconnect couldn't be implemented.